# What is the integral of $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 |x-y| dx dy$

Tags: calculus, integration

What is the integral of $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 |ax-by| dx dy $  for some constants $a,b$.

I was thinking to do split in on when it's positive and when it's negative like this
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \int_{x=0}^{x=\frac{a}{b}x} ax-by \, dx dy +\int_0^1 \int_{x=\frac{b}{a}y}^1 by-ax \,  dy dx
\end{align}

am I on the correct path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality, assume that $a \le b$, since if $a > b$, then we can simply interchange the variables of integration without affecting the value of the integral because the region of integration is symmetric with respect to the variables.

When $ax = by$, we have $y = mx$, where $m = a/b \le 1$ is the slope of the line through the origin.  Hence $$|ax - by| = \begin{cases} ax-by, & y < mx, \\ 0, & y = mx, \\ by-ax, & y > mx. \end{cases}$$  Now we have two cases:  either $m \ge 0$ or $m < 0$.  If the latter, then $|ax - by| = by-ax$ always prevails on $(x,y) \in [0,1]^2$, and the integral is simply the mean value of $by-ax$ at $(x,y) = (0,0)$ and $(x,y) = (1,1)$; i.e., $(b-a)/2$.

In the former case, we then have $$\begin{align*} \int_{x=0}^1 \int_{y=0}^1 |ax - by| \, dy \, dx &= \int_{x=0}^1 \left( \int_{y=0}^{mx} ax-by \, dy \, dx + \int_{y=mx}^1 by-ax \, dy \, dx \right) \\ &= \int_{x=0}^1 \left(\frac{(ax)^2}{b} - ax + \frac{b}{2}\right) \, dx \\ &= \frac{a^2}{3b} + \frac{b-a}{2}. \end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

You're on the correct path, but slightly confused.

You have to ensure the term remains positive when integrating with respect to $x$, when you split the interior.

So $x < by/a$ makes $by-ax>0$, and $x > by/a$ makes $ax-by>0$.

---

\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_0^1 |ax-by|\operatorname d x\operatorname d y
& = \int_0^1\left(\int_{0}^{by/a}(by-ax)\operatorname d x+\int_{by/a}^1 (ax-bx)\operatorname d x \right)\operatorname d y
\\[2ex]
& = \int_0^1 \int_0^{by/a}(by-ax)\operatorname d x\operatorname d y+\int_0^1\int_{by/a}^1 (ax-by)\operatorname d x \operatorname d y
\\[2ex]
& = \int_0^1 \frac{b^2y^2}{2a} \operatorname d y+\int_0^1\int_{by/a}^1 (ax-by)\operatorname d x \operatorname d y
\\ &\vdots
\end{align}

---

PS: this assumes $a,b$ are both positive, or both negative.  The answer is slightly different if they have opposing signage.